# How to enforce users to access artifacts from JFrog Artifactory with authentication?

Tags: artifactory

I am using JFrog Artifactory pro 7.31.10. I have already disabled the 'Allow Anonymous Access' checkbox. However, I could still able to download the artifacts without any authentication via curl.

I have noticed a [JFrog knowledge article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-generate-an-access-token-video/) which explains on setting up authentication token (Generate Access Token) for a group and members of that group can download using the token as bearer token. This model will not work for me as we could be having many application teams accessing the artifacts where we cannot share a common token. We want them to use their credentials instead of a common bearer token.

I want the anonymous access to be removed and users have to use their generic/application ids to get access to the Artifactory application and have to read/download the artifacts upon authentication. Uploading will be taken care via the CI Jobs. So, that should not be an issue.

Comment: Have you checked LDAP? JFrog Platform supports authentication via LDAP. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/LDAP

Comment: Blocking Anonymous access should not allow `curl` download. Can you provide reproduction steps in the original post so we can verify there's no bug here?

Comment: We are working on setting up SAML authentication with HA setup. We have 2 subdomains and on both sides, we have removed/unchecked "Allow Anonymous access" under Admin -> Security-> Settings. Then tried to download an artifact via curl without any authentication parameters and able to download the artifact.

Answer (score 2):

We have multiple option for users to Authenticate Artifactory like local Artifactory user, LDAP users and SAML users.
So if the users already have an LDAP account or an SAML account then they can use the same user details but LDAP or SAML had to be configured to Artifactory. below link will have the complete details:

- https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/LDAP
- https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/SAML+SSO
- https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-configure-an-artifactory-saml-sso-with-okta/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vCKSEUdmhc

And if you would like to create a local individual account to each users in Artifactory then we can create it with users, groups and grant the permissions to the required repository using permission targets. please refer the below link for complete details:

- https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Users+and+Groups
- https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Permissions

Comment: Thank you for the response.  In fact, we are setting up a ha system with SAML authentication. I ensured from UI that I got authenticated successfully. The anonymous option was unchecked  on both subdomains in the ha system. Then I tried a curl without any authentication parameters and was able to download successfully.